# Angular reload url but not the state view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on an application using OAuth2 protocol and I'm facing a problem with the UI.router module.

In fact, before each state changing, I need to test if the access token is stored in sessionStorage. So I use a `run` function like this one:

```
.run(['$state', '$window', '$location', '$rootScope', function ($state, $window, $location, $rootScope) {
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
                function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                    var accesstoken = sessionStorage.getItem('access_token');
                    if (!accesstoken) {

                        if ($location.url() !== '/access/connexion') {
                            $state.go('access.connexion', null, { reload: true });
                        }
                    }
                });
        }])
```

We admit now that I'm not connected and I try to access an URL like /users/12355 without access token:

The fact is that the URL refreshes, passing from /users/12355 to /access/connexion, but the view is still the one corresponding to /users/12355 (without any information loaded, cause I don't have access token)

I don't know what is the problem...

Moreover, if I `console.log` just above `$state.go`, it seems that I pass 400 time in this log. If I remove the `$state.go` function, I pass only one time...

Can you help me?

*NB : access.connexion is a root state*

Comment: From what you're saying, it seems as though `$location.url()` never evaluates to `/access/connexion`. What do you get when you log `$location.url()` just before the `$state.go`?

Comment: The $location.url() gives me "/access/connexion". The comparison is good

Answer (score 1):

Try to prevent state changing if token not found:

```
               if (!accesstoken) {
                     event.preventDefault();

                    if ($location.url() !== '/access/connexion') {
                        $state.go('access.connexion', null, { reload: true });
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `notify: true` to the `$state.go` params json should solve it,
change this:

```
$state.go('access.connexion', null, { reload: true });
```

to:

```
$state.go('access.connexion', null, { reload: true, notify: true });
```